# Knockout foreach binding calling click event while iteration

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm using knockout's foreach to draw table with clickable cells 
First column and table headers are used for population values inside table.

```
 <tbody>
        <!--ko foreach: $root.schedules -->
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: FromTo "></td>
            <!-- ko foreach: $root.weekdays -->
            <td data-bind="css:{selected:$root.objectForEdit().isSelected(id, $parent.Id) }, click: $root.changeEditObj(id, $parent.Id), with: $root.getDetailsModel(id, $parent.Id)">
                <span data-bind="text: lesson"></span>
            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
        <!--/ko-->
    </tbody>
```

As it can be seen from code snippet I'm using some css binding and also binding modal pop-up dialog to cell click event.

Table is drawn as expected, everything is working fine, but first time when form loads my modal form is poping up even there is no cell click happening. 
I've tried to figure out why this happening and found that inside iteration knockout is not only binding click event but calling click event's handler function (which is showing pop-up) as well.

I'm assuming problem is with knockout binding. Is there any solutions for this problem? How can I avoid function call inside foreach iteration ?

Comment: possible give us a fiddle reproduces your case . Try doing this `click:function(){ $root.changeEditObj(id, $parent.Id)}` instead of `$root.changeEditObj(id, $parent.Id)` . cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks  [Chaim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625737/haim770). I accidentally deleted his answer.

I've changed

```
click: $root.changeEditObj(id, $parent.Id)
```

to

```
click: $root.changeEditObj.bind(this, id, $parent.Id)
```

and it solved the problem.

This also worked fine:

```
click: function{$root.changeEditObj(id, $parent.Id)}
```

Additional Information on this can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#highlighter_578004) the correct syntax is `click: $root.changeEditObj.bind($data, id, $parent.Id)`